# Autopopulate summation of fields from a lookup object on a Main object field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom object called " Quotation", with a field called " Total Premium". The object has a look up relationship with another custom object " Cover". In the cover object i have field called " Gross Premium". I need that all the Cover object records added to the Quotation object, The gross premium from those will sum up and autopopulate in the Total premium field. Deleting or adding the records, should affect the Total premium field value.

[image]

I have written the below trigger, but its showing the error as

> Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: trigger trgSummarizeCover at
>   line 1 column 0

```
 trigger trgSummarizeCover on Cover__c (after delete, after insert, after update) {

  //Limit the size of list by using Sets which do not contain duplicate elements
  set<Id> QuotationIds = new set<Id>();

  //When adding new CustomObject or updating existing CustomObject
  if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Cover__c p : trigger.new){
      QuotationIds.add(p.Quotation__c);
    }
  }

  //When deleting CustomObject
  if(trigger.isDelete){
    for(Cover__c p : trigger.old){
      QuotationsIds.add(p.Quotation__c);
    }
  }

  //Map will contain one Quotation Id to one sum value
  map<Id,Double> QuotationMap = new map <Id,Double>();

  //Produce a sum of Cover__c and add them to the map
  //use group by to have a single Quotation Id with a single sum value
  for(AggregateResult q : [select Id,sum(Gross_premium_policy__c)
    from Cover__c where Quotation__c IN :QuotationIds group by Quotation__c]){
      QuotationMap.put((Id) q.get('Quotation__c'),(Double)q.get('expr0'));
  }

  List<Quotation__c> QuotationsToUpdate = new List<Quotation__c>();

  //Run the for loop on Quotation using the non-duplicate set of Quotation Ids
  //Get the sum value from the map and create a list of Quotations to update
  for(Quotation__c o : [Select Id, Total_Premium__c from Quotation__c where Id IN :QuotationIds]){
    Double Cover__c sum = QuotationMap.get(o.Id);
    o.Total_Premium__c = Cover__c sum;
    QuotationsToUpdate.add(o);
  }

  update QuotationsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Try using System.Trigger instead of Trigger in the body of code (eg: trigger.isInsert -> System.Trigger.IsInsert).

Comment: Hi rahul, i tried, til the same error showing.

Comment: Try creating a new trigger and update body block by block.

Comment: HI Rahul, i changed my trigger ass per below, now the error is different, can you plz check, whats wrong in line 16 and further lines. Thnx

Comment: Did you try what was mentioned earlier?

Comment: yes, i tried that. But the error is remaining same.